# how to know if a variable is not containing a number in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, numbers

so I know how to check if a variable contains numbers. like :

```
variable.isdigit
```

but how to know if its not containing a number and it have letters or symbols or... in it.

Comment: Is the question about the type of the variable or is about the contents of a string?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the documentation, e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp

- the opposite of .isdigit(): `not variable.isdigit()`

Comment: oh so much thanks ! i just needed the "not variable.isdigit()" .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to find out about the type of the variable is to use `type`:

```
>>> x=1.23
>>> y=3
>>> z='blah'
>>> print(type(x), type(y), type(z))
<class 'float'> <class 'int'> <class 'str'>
```

If you need boolean tests, you have a bunch of other `var.is*` options:

```
x.isalnum()       x.isdecimal()     x.islower()       x.isspace()
x.isalpha()       x.isdigit()       x.isnumeric()     x.istitle()
x.isascii()       x.isidentifier()  x.isprintable()   x.isupper()
```

Comment: so .... which one of these "is" booleans are for letters or symbols?

Comment: isalpha() is for alphabet letters; alnum() is for alphanumerical, so it returns true for letters and numbers; isascii() is for all ascii symbols. You can use the `and` and `or` and `not` logic to get precisely what you need.